# Is java.util.LinkedList possible to create a loop linkedlist?

Tags: java, iterator

I study `java.util.LinkedList` and `listIterator` for several days, and feel it is really hard to implement some functions such as loop `LinkedList`, and it does not have `Node` structure(I mean something like element, next node, previous node, I do know there is something similar in iterator), how you guys did this or you just create yourselves `LinkedList` class? Anyone can help me figure this out? I mean just use `java.util.LinkedList` collection.

Comment: Use an `Iterator`. Java's `LinkedList` will never hand you an instance of its internal `Node` implementation.

Comment: Thanks Buddy! I just want to make sure i did not missed anything in internal class about LinkedList.

Comment: As far as I know, only `Map` implementations will let you use their `Entry` objects. Typically Java wants to hide the actual implementation so that they can change it without affecting code.

Comment: By "loop `LinkedList`", do you mean a structure where a later node in the list can point back to an earlier node (creating a cycle)?

Comment: `LinkedList` deliberately disallows you from manipulating its internal structure, and disallows you from creating cyclic linked lists, etc.  It's designed to only let you use it as a normal `List`.

Comment: yes that is what i want.Any way to implement it?@ajb

Comment: @Louis Wasserman, Thank you! Do you mean it is just a normal List with an Iterator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `List` in Java is simply an ordered sequence of objects.  This concept doesn't allow for things like cycles, trees, etc.  There are several implementing classes like `LinkedList`, `ArrayList`, etc., that implement `List`s in different ways; the most important distinction between them is that some operations are faster with certain kinds of implementations (e.g. inserting is faster in a `LinkedList` than an `ArrayList`).  However, they all implement the same basic concept, and you can't use them for something different.

If you want a different kind of data structure, you'll either need to implement it yourself (which should not be too difficult) or look for some other, more general package to handle "graph" structures.  Unfortunately I don't know of one offhand.

Comment: It really helps me a lot. Thank you for your answer and patience.